# Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#HashTable'

Tags: sql-server

Here is the Error i am getting the select query from #hashtable data but cannot output it the txtfile

```
output
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL
Starting copy...
SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#HashTable'.
SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to resolve column level collations
NULL
BCP copy out failed
NULL
```

```
Select * from #TempData
DECLARE @OutputFile NVARCHAR(100) ,    @FilePath NVARCHAR(100) ,    @bcpCommand NVARCHAR(1000)



SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM #HashTable" queryout '
SET @FilePath = 'C:\test\'
SET @OutputFile = 'FileName1.txt'
SET @bcpCommand = @bcpCommand + @FilePath + @OutputFile + ' -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername
exec master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#HashTable is a temporary table that must be created in current session.

such as this :

```
--Create your own temp table named  #HASHTABLE
Select Id , Name 
INTO #HASHTABLE
From ExistingTable ;

Select * from #HashTable;


Drop Table #HashTable;
```

For more information see [this link](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-temporary-tables/)